# How to get the use regex to match years and months?

Tags: python, regex

Here's a sample data,

```
data_example1 = "1-19" #month, year (last two digits)
data_example2 = "12-21" #month, year (last two digits)
```

How can I write a regex to match this and then replace the year with zero padded.

This code seems to be working if month is single digit, how can I make it work for both one digit and two digit months. Also rather than `split("-")`, is there a way to use regex to zero pad the year alone.

```
if re.search("\d\-\d\d", data_example1):
   month, year = data_example1.split("-")
   cleaned_date = month + "-" + "00" + year # zero padded year
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work with 2 digit months?

Comment: I tried it with `12-21` and it worked.

Comment: @Barmar I mean the if condition I have written, if I do `re.search("\d\-\d\d", data_example2)`, this is failing, only data_example1 is working. I want a if condition to capture both data_example1 and data_example2

Comment: I tried that condition and it worked.

Comment: It would fail if you used `re.match()` instead of `re.search()`

Comment: @Barmar Got it...

Comment: Or if the regexp were anchored `^\d-\d\d'`

Comment: @Barmar But the problem is, my if condition is also working, when the search string is "0578-21", I only want it to match data_example1 and data_example2 type strings nothing else.

Comment: That's not what you wrote in the question.

Comment: @Barmar That was I meant to ask. Sorry. Its' fine `^\d\d?-\d\d$` seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a word boundary `\b` and quantifiers to match specific numbers of digits and not allow more.

Use `re.sub()` with capture groups and back-references.

```
if re.search(r"\b\d{1,2}-\d{2}\b", data_example1):
    cleaned_date = re.sub(r'\b(\d{1,2})-(\d{2})', r'\1-00\2', data_example1)
```

`{1,2}` means 1 or 2 of the previous pattern.

Comment: Can you tell me what does the \1 and \2 mean in re.sub ?

Comment: They're back-references. `\1` is replaced with whatever matched the first capture group. `\2` is replaced with whatever matched the second capture group.

Comment: Does these both \b and `^\d\d?-\d\d$`  work fine? or I need to use \b word boundary like u mentioned.

Comment: @SaiKumar `\b` is useful if you're trying to match part of the string, not the whole string. Like `We will be meeting on 12-21`

Comment: Understood. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an [optional quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
\d\d?\-\d\d
```

As suggested by Barmar, you could use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to prevent additional digits on either end:

```
\b\d\d?\-\d\d\b
```

An alternative here would be using `re.match`, or anchors, if the date is the only content in the string you are matching.

Comment: How does that add zeroes to the year?

Comment: You're answering a completely different question.

Comment: "This code seems to be working if month is single digit, how can I make it work for both one digit and two digit months."

Comment: Since it's not anchored, matching 1 digit will also match 2 digits.

Comment: Also use a word boundary to disallow more digits.

Comment: Thank you. Additional `\d?` helped as well.